# Rails 3 seed file loads everything but data for User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, seed

When I run `rake db:seed` for my Rails 3 app, all of the seed data except for the User data loads into my database. Here's a sample User that I create in my seeds file:

```
me = User.create(:email => 'me@gmail.com', :password => 'test', :profile => my_profile)
```

The profile for my user - `my_profile = Profile.create(..)` - loads. As do all of my other models. Is this the cause of my `seeds.rb` setup, or something in my `User.rb` model?

I'm using PostgreSQL, running `ruby 1.9.2` and `Rails 3.0.5`.

**UPDATE:** In my seed file, if I add an exclamation point after create I get a validation error on my email address:

```
Validation failed: Email is too short (minimum is 5 characters), Email is invalid
```

So that gets me closer to figuring out the issue. I'll mark this as answered and ask a new question about the validation error.

Comment: can you add **puts me.inspect** into seeds.rb and copy-paste the logs here please?

Comment: I tried putting `puts me.inspect` at the top and bottom of my seeds.rb and it kicked back an error `undefined local variable or method "me" for main:Object`.

Comment: What happens if you change it to `create!` ?

Comment: @tvalent2 try to put inspect method below the create

Comment: I'll give `create!` a go. What's strange is I've seeded the db this way at least 5-10 times before and never had a problem. Then when I tried to fix some of my rake errors and run `cancan` this went down.

Comment: Just updated my question. @Nick can you add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answered? I couldn't get puts me.inspect to give anything except `undefined local variable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.create!` instead to make it throw and exception if something is going wrong with validation.